# Metro waiting on exp://127.0.0.1:19000 browser not opening automatically after the command expo start

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

[QRCode not opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28U0i.png)

last time I use to switch from LAN to Tunnel connection so that  QRcode can work, now  the browser can't open automatically and am struggling to connect to the server
[image]

Comment: Are you on the same network as the device displaying the QR code?

Comment: yes I'm connected to the same network, I normally use a hotspot, I once come across this error but I used to switch from LAN to Tunnel connection but now the browser aint (after the command expo start ) opening automatically so that I can choose the connection type

Comment: Are you trying to use React Native for web?

Comment: I'm still a beginner but what I'm trying to do is to connect the android phone using expo go app (scanning QRcode) so that I can see any changes on it, not on the web

Comment: i have managed to fix the erro using  npx expo start --tunnel